# Add string headers to double columns Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a double matrix `A` of size `10x10`. What I want to do is I have a string array of size `1x10`. I want to replace the first row in matrix `A` with this array of strings to be the headers of these columns. Same with the first column. If anyone could please advise how this can be done in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For MATLAB R2013b or higher

If you have at least MATLAB R2013b or higher, you can use the [`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) function to present the values in your desired format.  Let's assume that your matrix is stored in `A`. Next, assuming your row headers are in a cell array and stored in `row` and your column headers are stored in a cell array called `col`, try this:

Try this:

```
T = array2table(A, 'RowNames', row, 'VariableNames', col);
```

Here's an example:

```
>> A = [1 12 30.48; 2 24 60.96; 3 36 91.44]
>> col = {'Feet', 'Inches', 'Centimeters'};
>> row = {'Number 1', 'Number 2', 'Number 3'};
>> T = array2table(A, 'RowNames', row, 'VariableNames', col)

T = 

            Feet    Inches    Centimeters
            ____    ______    ___________

 Number 1     1       12        30.48      
 Number 2     2       24        60.96      
 Number 3     3       36        91.44
```

## For MATLAB R2013a or lower

If you have R2013a or lower, you have no choice but to use a cell array for this.  You can only achieve mixed data types in a matrix with a cell array.  What you'll need to do is convert each number into an individual cell in a cell array.  I'm going to introduce you to an undocumented function: [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function).  You are able to print matrices directly to cell arrays.

Therefore, try doing this, assuming that `row` contains your strings in a cell array for the row header of size `1 x N` and `col` contains your strings in a cell array for the column header of size `1 x N`.  With your matrix `A`:

```
Acell = sprintfc('%f', A); %// Convert matrix to cells
out = [' ', row; col.', Acell]; %// Generate final matrix
```

`out` contains your desired matrix.  Here's an example:

```
>> A = [1 12 30.48; 2 24 60.96; 3 36 91.44];
>> Acell = sprintfc('%f', A);
>> row = {'Feet', 'Inches', 'Centimeters'};
>> col = {'Number 1', 'Number 2', 'Number 3'};
>> out = [' ', row; col.', Acell]

out = 

    ' '              'Feet'        'Inches'       'Centimeters' 
    'Number 1'       '1.000000'    '12.000000'    '30.480000'
    'Number 2'       '2.000000'    '24.000000'    '60.960000'
    'Number 3'       '3.000000'    '36.000000'    '91.440000'
```

Comment: and how to get rid of this single quote? also what if I wanted to replace headers with first cell in rows as well?

Comment: @shepherd - You can't.  Those are there because it's a cell array.  What you could do is try `celldisp`.... or you can use `table`.  Do you have MATLAB R2013b or higher?

Comment: OK.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @shepherd - I've just updated my post :) Take a look

Comment: Okay, I did it but I can't find `T` in my workspace to display or view it, why?

Comment: Are you sure??? Type in `whos T` and see what you get.  Also make sure you check my most updated post.  I've made some significant changes.

Comment: it was my mistake, sorry. will check the full solution now.

Comment: @shepherd - No problem.  I made a slight typo too.  Please make sure you refresh the page.

Comment: okay. Do you know how I can save this table into an excel file?

Comment: @shepherd - Yup.  Use `writetable`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html... so do something like this: `writetable(T, 'test.xls');`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75089/discussion-between-shepherd-and-rayryeng).

Comment: I tried but it said `Could not start Excel server for export.  Export to a text file instead.`